# How to get table row value into text field in JavaScript..?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I Create a Table Using this code,

```
 <table class="table table-green table-hover" id="tblk"></table>
```

And I Use This JavaScrip Function (For A Button) to add Rows when I add data in to table,

```
function addRow() {
  var custid = document.getElementById('InputCusomerID').value
  var custname = document.getElementById('InputCusomerName').value
  var itemid = document.getElementById('InputItemID').value
  var table = document.getElementById('tblk')
  var row = table.insertRow(0)
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
  cell1.innerHTML = custid
  cell2.innerHTML = custname
  cell3.innerHTML = itemid
}
```

When I clicked a table row, I need to get a table Row value into my input text field

***This Is my JavaScrip Function to get table rows to value into my text field..,***

```
var table = document.getElementById('tblk'),
  rIndex
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  table.rows[i].onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('InputCusomerID').value = this.cells[0].innerHTML
    document.getElementById('InputCusomerName').value = this.cells[1].innerHTML
    document.getElementById('InputItemID').value = this.cells[2].innerHTML
}
}
```

**But My Code Is Not Working I Can't Get Table Row Value Into My Text Field.
Can You Help Me With That Problem..?
Thank You Very Much..!**

```js
function addRow() {
  var custid = document.getElementById('InputCusomerID').value
  var custname = document.getElementById('InputCusomerName').value
  var itemid = document.getElementById('InputItemID').value
  var table = document.getElementById('tblk')
  var row = table.insertRow(0)
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
  cell1.innerHTML = custid
  cell2.innerHTML = custname
  cell3.innerHTML = itemid
}

var table = document.getElementById('tblk'),
  rIndex
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('InputCusomerID').value = this.cells[0].innerHTML
    document.getElementById('InputCusomerName').value = this.cells[1].innerHTML
    document.getElementById('InputItemID').value = this.cells[2].innerHTML
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-green table-hover" id="tblk"></table>
```

Comment: `console.log(this)` as the first thing inside your onclick event handler.  See what it prints in the console

Comment: Also turning this into an [mcve] could be very helpful to readers.

Comment: script.js:119 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: You would not have gotten that error from the console log, but hey, you now see an error you need to address.

Comment: I made snippet out of your code, fix ti to make [mre], run-able snippet out of your problem.

Comment: This Is my first time on StackOverflow.I am really sorry about my mistake.

Comment: Np, we are here to help, but you just deleted a snippet I made. The problem you are asking is about table you made, and how to get value out of it. And we dont see half of your code related to those issues. Like I said, please read this: [mre]  and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask use <> button in editor to make run-able snippet

Comment: I Am Realy Sorry. It was my mistake. (If I Replaced My Code ) Can U Make That Agin Please ..?

Comment: Also this is NEVER a good way too describe the problem: But My Code Is Not Working . be specific, what exactly in all this dues not work, Do you get an error, and what is it?

Comment: My error is, If I apply the js function to get table row value into my input tex field, It's not working. There is now an error. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but it's not working because your click listener is being called before your table is populated. See my code.

```js
function addRow() {
  var custid = document.getElementById('InputCusomerID').value
  var custname = document.getElementById('InputCusomerName').value
  var itemid = document.getElementById('InputItemID').value
  var table = document.getElementById('tblk')
  var row = table.insertRow(0)
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
  cell1.innerHTML = custid
  cell2.innerHTML = custname
  cell3.innerHTML = itemid
  
  setListeners();
}

var table = document.getElementById('tblk'),
  rIndex;
  
function setListeners() {
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  table.rows[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    document.getElementById('InputCusomerID').value = "result: " + this.cells[0].innerHTML
    document.getElementById('InputCusomerName').value = "result: " + this.cells[1].innerHTML
    document.getElementById('InputItemID').value = "result: " + this.cells[2].innerHTML
  });
}
}


addRow();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="InputCusomerID" value="a" />
<input type="text" id="InputCusomerName" value="b" />
<input type="text" id="InputItemID" value="c" />

<table class="table table-green table-hover" id="tblk"></table>
```

Comment: It's Work..Thank You Very Much, Sir..!